# slds css is not loaded. "Bad Gateway"

Tags: visualforce, lightning, css

I use

```
<apex:slds>
```

in my Visualforce Page.
It has been working well for long time but recently some users suddenly can not load slds css.
I found that the following error occurs.

> https:///slds/css/
>   ..(token?)../min/scoped/one:oneNamespace,force:sldsTokens,force:base,force:formFactorLarge/slds.css
>   net::ERR_ABORTED 502 (Bad Gateway)

I tried super reload but still same error.
This error happens both Chrome and IE11.
How can I fix this error? Please help me...
Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

I still don't know why this issue happens but I fixed it by changing "Site URL Redirects" as follows.

Source URL : /
Target URL : /myCommunityName/

Source URL : /
Target URL : /myCommunityName/communityHomePageName/

The error occurs every time when I use IE with F12 debug page.
After login to my community, css is not loaded.
But if I jump to another community page, css is loaded.